# type parameter T has incompatible upper bounds view and fragment

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFeJh.png)

type parameter T has incompatible upper bounds view and fragment

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please try to post your code as text, not as images

Comment: [Why screenshots are discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/85421)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast it to `FrameLayout`. So it becomes `parentFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) getActivit().findViewById(R.id.register_frameLayout)`